# How do I add arrows in my post?

Tags: support, markdown

Sometimes, I see people posting this:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Or this:

> Go to **File** → **Preferences**.

How can I add these super awesome arrows?

I know I can copy the arrows from another post, or save them on my machine in a text file, but those are not "quick and easy" solutions.

Comment: On *some* international keyboard layouts, the arrow keys are accessible via AltGr+(Y/Z), AltGr+U, AltGr+Shift+U, and AltGr+I. No idea which ones have it though. You can also [modify your layout](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345007/typing-upwards-arrow-with-a-keyboard-shortcut) to include them.

Comment: So you post a question where the source contains `&rightarrow;` asking about how to include super awesome arrows in the source?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I use these entities: `&larr;`, `&uarr;`, `&rarr;` and `&darr;` only. It's faster: ←, ↑, → and ↓.

Comment: Ha, even better!

Answer (score 29):

You can add the arrows by simply typing the below:

```
&uparrow;
```

That will give you ↑.

Similarly, `&downarrow;`, `&rightarrow;`, and `&leftarrow;` give you ↓, →, and ←.

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution would be to set up [an `.Xcompose` file for custom compose key sequences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence).

This is what I use:

```
include "%L"
# SINGLE ARROWS
<Multi_key> <Left> <Left>       : "←"   leftarrow   # LEFTWARDS ARROW
<Multi_key> <Up> <Up>           : "↑"   uparrow     # UPWARDS ARROW
<Multi_key> <Right> <Right>     : "→"   rightarrow  # RIGHTWARDS ARROW
<Multi_key> <Down> <Down>       : "↓"   downarrow   # DOWNWARDS ARROW
<Multi_key> <Left> <Right>      : "↔"   U2194           # LEFT RIGHT ARROW (kragen's)
<Multi_key> <Right> <Left>      : "↔"   U2194           # LEFT RIGHT ARROW (kragen's)
<Multi_key> <Right> <ampersand> <Left>  : "⥂"   U21F5       # 
<Multi_key> <Left> <ampersand> <Right>  : "⥄"   U21F5       # 
<Multi_key> <Left> <equal> <Right>      : "⇌"   U21F5       # 
<Multi_key> <Right> <equal> <Left>      : "⇌"   U21F5       # 
<Multi_key> <Up> <Down>         : "↕"   U2195           # UP DOWN ARROW (kragen's)
<Multi_key> <Up> <ampersand> <Down>     : "⇵"   U21F5       #
<Multi_key> <Down> <ampersand> <Up>     : "⇵"   U21F5       #
<Multi_key> <Down> <ampersand> <Down>   : "⇊"   U21F5       # 
<Multi_key> <Up> <ampersand> <Up>       : "⇈"   U21F5       #
# DOUBLE ARROWS
<Multi_key> <equal> <Right> <Right> : "⇒"   U21D2       # RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <greater>       : "⇒"   U21D2       # RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Left> <Left>   : "⇐"   U21D0       # LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <less>          : "⇐"   U21D0       # RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Left> <Right>  : "⇔"   U21D4       # LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Right> <Left>  : "⇔"   U21D4       # LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Up> <Up>       : "⇑"   U21D1       # UPWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Down> <Down>   : "⇓"   U21D3       # DOWNWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <Up> <Down>     : "⇕"   U21D5       # UP DOWN DOUBLE ARROW
# SPECIAL ARROWS
<Multi_key> <Left> <o>          : "⟲"   U27F2       # ANTICLOCKWISE GAPPED CIRCLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Right> <o>         : "⟳"   U27F3       # CLOCKWISE GAPPED CIRCLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Left> <c>          : "↺"   U21BA       # ANTICLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Right> <c>         : "↻"   U21BB       # CLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Left> <w>          : "⇜"   U21DC       # LEFTWARDS SQUIGGLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Right> <w>         : "⇝"   U21DD       # RIGHTWARDS SQUIGGLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Left> <bar>            : "⥖"   U21E4       #
<Multi_key> <Right> <bar>           : "⥗"   U21E5       #
<Multi_key> <Right> <minus>         : "⤼"   U21E2       # RIGHTWARDS DASHED ARROW
<Multi_key> <Right> <plus>          : "⥅"   U21E2       # RIGHTWARDS DASHED ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <slash> <greater>   : "⇏"   U21D2       # RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <equal> <slash> <less>  : "⇍"   U21D0       # LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
<Multi_key> <Down> <minus> <Right>  : "↪"   U27F2       # 
<Multi_key> <Down> <equal> <Right>  : "➥"   U27F2       #
# MATHEMATICAL OPERATORS AND SYMBOLS
<Multi_key> <exclam> <equal>        : "≠"   U2260       # NOT EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <a> <q> <u>         : "≙"   U2260       # NOT EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <a> <p> <r>         : "≈"   U2248           # ALMOST EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <less> <equal>      : "≤"   U2264       # LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <greater> <equal>       : "≥"   U2265       # GREATER-THAN OR EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <plus> <less>           : "≪"   U226A       # MUCH LESS-THAN
<Multi_key> <plus> <greater>        : "≫"   U226B       # MUCH GREATER-THAN
<Multi_key> <equal> <d> <e> <f>     : "≝"   U225D       # EQUAL TO BY DEFINITION
<Multi_key> <equal> <question>      : "≟"   U225f       # QUESTIONED EQUAL TO
<Multi_key> <8> <8>                     : "∞"  U221E            # INFINITY
<Multi_key> <o> <1>         : "·"   periodcentered  # MIDDLE DOT
<Multi_key> <o> <2>         : "•"   U2022       # BULLET
<Multi_key> <o> <3>         : "⚫"   U2022       # BULLET
<Multi_key> <parenleft> <plus> <parenright>     : "⊕"  U2295    # CIRCLED PLUS
<Multi_key> <parenleft> <minus> <parenright>    : "⊖"  U2296    # CIRCLED MINUS
<Multi_key> <1> <3>                     : "⅓"  U2153            # VULGAR FRACTION ONE THIRD
<Multi_key> <2> <3>                     : "⅔"  U2154            # VULGAR FRACTION TWO THIRDS
<Multi_key> <1> <5>                     : "⅕"  U2155            # VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH
<Multi_key> <2> <5>                     : "⅖" U2156             # VULGAR FRACTION TWO FIFTHS
<Multi_key> <3> <5>                     : "⅗" U2157             # VULGAR FRACTION THREE FIFTHS
<Multi_key> <4> <5>                     : "⅘" U2158             # VULGAR FRACTION FOUR FIFTHS
<Multi_key> <1> <6>                     : "⅙" U2159             # VULGAR FRACTION ONE SIXTH
<Multi_key> <5> <6>                     : "⅚" U215A             # VULGAR FRACTION FIVE SIXTHS
<Multi_key> <1> <8>                     : "⅛" U215B             # VULGAR FRACTION ONE EIGHTH
<Multi_key> <3> <8>                     : "⅜" U215C             # VULGAR FRACTION THREE EIGHTHS
<Multi_key> <5> <8>                     : "⅝" U215D             # VULGAR FRACTION FIVE EIGHTHS
<Multi_key> <7> <8>                     : "⅞" U215E             # VULGAR FRACTION SEVEN EIGHTHS
# MISC SYMBOLS
<Multi_key> <colon> <parenright>        : "☺"   U263A           # WHITE SMILING FACE
<Multi_key> <colon> <parenleft>         : "☹"   U2639           # WHITE FROWNING FACE
<Multi_key> <y> <y> <1>         : "✓"   U2713       # CHECK MARK
<Multi_key> <y> <y> <2>         : "✔"   U2714       # HEAVY CHECK MARK
<Multi_key> <n> <n> <1>         : "✗"   U2717       # BALLOT X
<Multi_key> <n> <n> <2>         : "✘"   U2718       # HEAVY BALLOT X
<Multi_key> <r> <a> <d>         : "☢"   U2622       # RADIOACTIVE SIGN
<Multi_key> <b> <h>         : "☣"   U2623       # BIOHAZARD SIGN
<Multi_key> <z> <a> <p> <1>     : "⚡"   U26A1       # HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN
<Multi_key> <slash> <slash> <slash> : "↯"   U26A1       # 
<Multi_key> <z> <a> <p> <2>     : "ϟ"   U26A1       # 
<Multi_key> <m> <e> <d>         : "⚕"   U2695       # STAFF OF AESCULAPIUS
<Multi_key> <o> <minus> <plus>      : "♀"   U2640       # FEMALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <o> <minus> <greater>   : "♂"   U2642       # MALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <t> <r> <a> <n> <s>         : "⚥"   U26A5           # MALE AND FEMALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <s> <u> <n>         : "☉"   U2609       # SUN (Sunday)
<Multi_key> <g> <a> <y>                 : "⚣"   U26A3       # DOUBLED MALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <l> <e> <s> <b> <i> <a> <n> : "⚢"   U26A2       # DOUBLED FEMALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <h> <e> <t> <e> <r> <o>     : "⚤"   U26A4       # INTERLOCKED FEMALE AND MALE SIGN
<Multi_key> <O> <X>         : "☠"   U2620       # SKULL AND CROSSBONES
<Multi_key> <numbersign> <G>            : ""   U0001d11e  # MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF
<Multi_key> <p> <p> <p>         : "Ⓟ"   U2718       # 
<Multi_key> <k> <k> <k>         : "Ⓚ"   U2718       # 
<Multi_key> <t> <t> <t>         : "Ⓣ"   U2718       #
<Multi_key> <s> <s> <s>         : "Ⓢ"   U2718       #
<Multi_key> <d> <d> <d>         : "Ⓓ"   U2718       #
<Multi_key> <e> <e> <e>         : "Ⓔ"   U2718       #
<Multi_key> <minus> <minus>     : "−"   U2212       #
```

(Sorry for the bad formatting, I should really stop using tabs)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This website provides more information: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/kbd

Also in most browsers you can highlight it, right click, and `view selection source`.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps... Have Fun!

Comment: Thanks for your post SoCalDiegoRob! Although I was looking for a way to put arrows in my post (left, right, up and down), and not necessarily the `<kbd>` tag. Also, "view source" shows an actual arrow, not the code that was used to make it (which is `&uparrow;`).

Comment: @Alaa Ok I see, sorry about that. I thought you were asking about the keystrokes also, but you were just using them as an example of the arrow use. Glad you found your answer though...